# Project Tango -Start of Service Coordinate System, C API

Tags: c, coordinate-transformation, google-project-tango

I am working with the Motion Tracking app, trying to record the pose data on C API. The pose data is recorded with respect to the Start_Of_Service coordinate system. I am having trouble understanding this coordinate system.

- Is the Z+ always aligned with gravity?
- The back of the device is used as the Y axis?
- The documentation says that the X-Y plane is perpendicular to Z and level with the ground. If Z+ is aligned with gravity and the Tango tablet is at an angle with gravity, how are the X and Y aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the Z+ always aligned with gravity?

Per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/coordinate-systems):

> Project Tango uses a right-handed, local-level frame for the START_OF_SERVICE and AREA_DESCRIPTION coordinate frames. This convention sets the Z-axis aligned with gravity, with Z+ pointed upwards, and the X-Y plane is perpendicular to gravity and locally level with the ground plane.

So yes. For START_OF_SERVICE and AREA_DESCRIPTION base frames.

> The back of the device is used as the Y axis?

Per the docs:

> Project Tango uses the direction the back of the device is pointed when the service started as the Y axis

Perpendicular to the device with y+ pointing out the back.

> The documentation says that the X-Y plane is perpendicular to Z and level with the ground. If Z+ is aligned with gravity and the Tango tablet is at an angle with gravity, how are the X and Y aligned?

[image]

Imagine you are holding the device in the image at the START_OF_SERVICE Frame.  Notice how the device is square with the room.

[image]

Now tilt the tablet forward or back about the x axis.  The device moves, but all the axes stay the same.

[image]

Now rotate the device right or left about the y axis.  All the axes stay the same.

So if your device is tilted, first rotate the device about the y axis, then about the x axis until the tablet screen aligns with the z axis...at which point it is easier to visualize where your axes are located.

Comment: Thank you Aaron!, I now have some clarity on my problem